# Dropdown style does not working in react class

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm getting starting in React and I do not know if I'm missing something. There is no other CSS file, this is unique. The style is not being applied.

index.css

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
  
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
  
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
  
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}
        
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}
  
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

App.js

```
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            < div >
                <Header />
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <button class="dropbtn">Name</button>
                    <div class="dropdownContent">
                        <a href="#">One</a>
                        <a href="#">Two</a>
                        <a href="#">Three</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div >
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Not all CSS is being applied, I think the only CSS being applied is in the button

[image]

I imported that CSS file inside App.js `import 'index.css'` Can anyone help or suggest anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `dropdown-content` in css file to `dropdownContent` as you have used in your JSX.

Currently some of your css must be getting applied which aren't dependent on `dropdownContent`.

Also recommended way for adding class in React is **className**.

Answer (score 2):

Try to change `class` attribute to `className`:

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <div className="dropdown">
                    <button className="dropbtn">Name</button>
                    <div className="dropdownContent">
                        <a href="#">One</a>
                        <a href="#">Two</a>
                        <a href="#">Three</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default App;
```